# Is there a general technique to obtain asymptotic expansion of integral of the form $\int_0^{x} d x' f(x') $ as $x \to \infty$.

Tags: calculus, integration

In particular, I wish to find a proof of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}  = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ using such a method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want a general technique for finding the asymptotic behaviour of *any* primitive? It does not look so easy, to me.

Comment: I am okay with specific techniques, in particular one that works for $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ to produce the series given here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28x%29%2Fx

Comment: That series can be obtained by writing $\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dx - \int_t^\infty \frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$ then repeatedly using integration by parts on the second integral.

Comment: Ah. That is useful. Doesn't help with the original problem of the full definite integral. But, this solution to that series makes it seem like that is not the right way to compute the full definite integral. Thank you.